# Stylerframe to html in a Plotly Graph

Tags: python, html, dataframe, styling

I have recently started learning `Python`. To automate a report, I'm reading excel data and plotting some `graphs` using `Plotly`. But I also want to display a subset of the table data as-is i.e. retaining all the formatting (esp. the formatted colors of the underlying sheet)

I'm able to read the table with the same formating as the table using `StylerFrame`

```py
sf = StyleFrame.read_excel(s_filename, engine='openpyxl',read_style=True)
```

but don't know how to add this to the `html`.

I have tried the workaround where I read the table as a `dataframe`, `style` it and `render()` it to an `html`. This works.

But I would prefer to show the `StylerFrame` object on an `Html` instead. Please help.